# Finity to Infinity?

Tags: infinity

The list of all whole numbers is infinite. Can numbers start from something trivial such as 0, 1 and then reach infinity?

As per my understanding, infinity is fully formed, perfectly symmetrical, which means to say that a part(small or big) of infinity is also an infinity(like a fractal, wherein each part is the same as a whole). So that would imply that infinity is one as a concept and there are no different classes of infinity, and we tend to classify infinities for the sake of simplification in mathematics.

Comment: As I understand it, infinity is in mathematics, physics and philosophy a catchy term for pretty much everything we cannot conceive because it transcends our ability to grasp things. Even in formal mathematics, there is positive and negative infinity, see diverging series.

Comment: As you correctly say, this is **not** the point of view of mathematics.; thus, in mathematics, it is not true that "a part(small or big) of infinity is also an infinity". The set **{1}** is a part (a subset) of the *infinite* set **N** of all *natural* numbers, but it is **not** infinite.

Comment: Are you referring to the mathematical concept of infinity or infinity in philosophy/logic? If the former, the question would probably be better answered at [Mathematics-SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Numbers don't "reach infinity." Infinity is not a really high number. There are provably different infinities (see Cantor's diagonalization argument). There is also the colloquial concept "infinitesimal," which itself is not an actual mathematical concept. Instead, one talks about values being sufficiently small (see epsilon-delta proofs).

Comment: This appears to be a question where the OP could benefit greatly by reading up on infinity in math. (This applies regardless of whether the question is about the mathematical concept or trying to be about an esoteric thing called infinity)

Answer (score 4):

It would be correct to say: "An infinite set has proper subsets which are infinite again."

Otherwise trivial counter examples exist as Mauro points out.

The concept of infinity as detected by Cantor is much more subtle than a simple argumentation with symmetry captures.

I agree with Mauro that Cantor detected an infinite number of different kinds of infinity. It is a fascinating domain from mathematical set theory. See my comments to @Iowa for some example definitions and results.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere.
As per my analysis, from the point of view of mathematics, the more appropriate term to use would be "Uncountable", which would instantly imply it is finite but very large and starts from a finite point.. That would make perfect sense. 

Same goes to the size of the universe, which physicists should say, might be very big(uncountable), rather than, might be infinite, which would otherwise imply that every point in the universe would be infinite, and as bright as a surface of a star.

Comment: Same goes for Cantor's definition, It should be different kinds of uncountable, rather than, different kinds of infinities.
The very definition of infinity is something that is fractal-y infinite or else it can never be infinite.

Comment: @Iowa According to set theory: 1) Two sets have the same cardinality if and only if a bijective map exists from one to the other. 2) A given set is infinite if and only if it contains a proper subset with the same cardinality (Dedekind). 3) Equivalently: A given set is infinite if and only if an injective map exists from the set of natural numbers to the given set. 4) A given set is infinite countable if and only if it has the same cardinalitc as the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @Iowa 5) Cantor detected that infinite sets exist which are uncountable, e.g. the set of real numbers. 6) Cantor detected that the cardinality of the power set is always strictly bigger than the cardinality of the original set. Hence starting with the power set of the set of natural numbers you get step by step an infinite number of uncountable infinite cardinalities. But note: The class of all cardinals is not countable.

Comment: @Iowa "uncountable" has a very specific meaning when you are talking about mathematical concepts of infinity.  That meaning is not consistent with your usage.  You're free to make up any terminology you please, but its easier to communicate your ideas if they use the typically accepted terminology.

Answer (score 2):

> The list of whole numbers is infinite; can one start from zero, one, two and reach infinity?

Aristotle had a concept of *potential* infinity, in that one can keep going towards infinity, but never reach it; this concept is the one still used in physical thinking - which is why whenever they find an infinity in a theory it's a sign of something having gone wrong somewhere; one might say *potential* infinity is then a concept of *onto-logic*.

Mathematics recently has gone in a different direction, essentially as Wehler points out from Cantors conceptualisation of infinity; but to start this off, they *cannot* simply go from 0, 1, 2 ...; they need to assert a *new* axiom:

> I: there is an infinite set

So, in a way your intuition was correct.

> Infinity, is fully formed and perfectly symmetrical

This sounds rather like Parmenides in-finite; ie not finite; where finitude is identified with the phenomenal world and the non-finite, the Parmenidean One is perfectly 'well-rounded'; ie  symmetrical.

But then you say this:

> which means a part of infinity is like infinity

Which is how, modernly, we understand we have an infinite set - which was one of the 'inputs' into Cantors theory; I mean it was thinking over and through this paradox that helped form the modern theory of the mathematical infinite.

Comment: Can the down-voter or some-one sympathetic to the down-vote please explain where my stab at an explanation has gone wrong? Or are they simply prejudicial against concepts of infinity that are *philosophical*, rather than the merely *mathematical* mainstream?

Comment: I am just a sympathetic someone, but to me phrases like "Infinity, is fully formed and perfectly symmetrical" don't make sense.. trying to attach adjectives like "symmetrical" to something that has not been defined in the first place. It may be that you dislike the "mathematical mainstream" approach, but it would be good to provide an alternative, viable approach. Talking about non defined things in hand-waving sort of way it's a waste of time from my point of view. But of course I have a mathematical approach so I'd be happy to change my point of view throgh a discussion :-)

Comment: @ant: it's not that I dislike the mathematical mainstream - I know it as well as any one, if not *more*; and I do mention it;  spheres are perfectly symmetrical, and for anyone with a knowledge of the history of philosophy, mathematics and physics - the parallels are obvious; my dislike is of *only* the mainstream; there are alternative insights - it's well to remember that Cantorian infinities

Comment: was a minoritarian position when it was invented; in fact, Cantor was driven to nervous breakdown by the mathematical conservatism of the time; Brouwer, the inventor of intuitionism was warned by his advisor to get a tenured position before expounding on his alternative mathematical philosophy.

Comment: If you look at Brouwers original work, to some extent it is hand-wavy - by today's standards, very hand-wavy: the two acts of intuitionism; now we have Heyting algebras...in correspondance to Boolean algebras!

Comment: But thanks for commenting - it's good to know why.

Comment: Well of course I can't speak for who actually downvoted this post :) Regarding your argument, I don't get your point: 1) You mean that from the knowledge of what symmetrical means with respect to a sphere it is obvious what "Symmetrical infinity" is? Well I have no idea. Starting to define Infinity would be a good start. 2) It's true that, breaking away from the mainstream is met with skepticism (sometimes even too much so). But Cantor theories were *rigorous*, albeit radical.

Comment: I can't speak for Brouwers work having never read it, but I fail to see how it would be a justification for using words without having defined them; after all Heyting algebras *were* introduced to address the problem, and to me they seem a very important part of the process (if not the most important)

Comment: Sure - understood; for Brouwer - I'm simply pointing out that before rigorous conceptualisations are made there is a period of unrigorous conceptualisations beforehand, especially if it's a radically new step; Heyting couldn't have done what he did without Brouwer first taking the step he did; Heytings work, as important as it is, took off from Brouwer; it's the OP that used the word 'symmetrical' and I said it *sounds rather like*, which is hardly making definitive statements ...

Comment: @ant: you're more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question : "Can numbers start from something trivial such as 0, 1 and then reach infinity?"

This is a mathematical question and the mathematical answer is no. To understand why the answer is no requires some philosophical considerations.

To best way to understand why is to consider Cantor's original "three principles of *ordinal* generation".  (Here, an *ordinal* is just a certain type of a set.)

The three principles exploit the notion of successor, limit, and supremum. Rather than get bogged down in technical details I will appeal to your intuition here. When we apply any one of these principles to a finite collection of ordinals (numbers) - e.g., {0} or {0,1} - we generate one new ordinal (number).  Adding one to a finite number yields a finite number and therefore the three principles of ordinal generation do not allow us to escape the finite domain.  At this stage, we cannot take the supremum of all finite numbers to obtain an infinite set since we have not yet generated all finite numbers.

The only way to formally obtain an infinite set is to introduce an axiom that asserts the existence of an infinite set - the so-called [Axiom of Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity).

Once we have asserted the existence of an infinite set, we can continue to apply the three principles to generate new infinite sets which are mathematically distinct from that set identified by the axiom of infinity.

---

You then say "As per my understanding, infinity is fully formed, perfectly symmetrical".  This is not entirely correct.  Certainly those sets formed by the three principles are fully formed in the sense of being well-defined. However, in the case of infinite sets, these sets are not symmetrical since, for example, there is a smallest whole number but no greatest whole number.  Other infinite sets may have a *least* member and a *greatest* member, but "in between" there are subsets with no greatest member.

It is also important to understand that our intuition of the infinite extends beyond those well-formed sets generated by the three principles to what Cantor called *the absolute infinite*.  These collections are not well-formed.  These are inconsistent infinities such as the collection of all well-formed sets.  The inconsistency of this collection is witnessed by Russell's famous paradox.

---

Finally, you say "So that would imply that infinity is one as a concept and there are no different classes of infinity, and we tend to classify infinities for the sake of simplification in mathematics."  This is not correct as a statement about mathematical infinity.  As we have already noted, once we have asserted the existence of an infinite set we can continue to apply the three principles of ordinal generation to generate new sets which are mathematically distinct.